# BlackBerry Menu activates Transition

Tags: blackberry

When the user click something in my App it activates the Menu, which pops up on screen. However this Menu also activates a transition, which I can't seem to turn off. So the screen does some weird sliding thing which looks really bad. I have set some global transitions, and this is the only place they are causing a problem.

Is there a way I can access the screen that the default menu pushes so I can set a new empty transition? Or is there any other way to control the transition without going back and turning off the global transitions and setting them for every individual page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a global sliding transition (TransitionContext.TRANSITION_SLIDE), make sure to set the style to TransitionContext.STYLE_OVER, since the default is TransitionContext.STYLE_PUSH which causes the ugly screen slide when opening the menu.

Up-sliding menu example would look like:

```
TransitionContext transition = new TransitionContext(TransitionContext.TRANSITION_SLIDE);
transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_DURATION, 150);
transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_DIRECTION,  TransitionContext.DIRECTION_UP);
transition.setIntAttribute(TransitionContext.ATTR_STYLE, TransitionContext.STYLE_OVER);
Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setTransition(null, null, UiEngineInstance.TRIGGER_PUSH, transition);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up setting more customized transitions which fixed the problem, but glad to know there is a solution.